# how can i change all the labels font in one command

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

if i have 3 labels called total,score and name and i want to change the font of the text i use this command

```
[total setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:22]];
[score setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:22]];
[name setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:22]];
```

what if i have like more than 20 labels in one view and all with different names like total score name.

is there a shorter way to change the font for all of them to the same font type ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**do fast enumeration..**

```
 for( UIView *view in self.subviews)
    {
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel Class]])
    {
    [(UILabel *)view setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:22]];

    }
    }
```

Comment: can you please explain more how to do it ? i`m new to this stuff

Comment: copy this code to your code(wherever you want to change the font.. basically you are checking each view in your view.. if it is type of UIlabel so changing its font.. this code will change all labels font..

Comment: thanks, it worked , but i needed to change self.subviews to self.view.subviews and UILabel Class to UILabel class

Answer (score 2):

For specific label;

```
    for( UIView *v in self.view.subviews) {
        if([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel Class]]) {
            if (v.tag == 1453)
               [(UILabel *)v setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:22]];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This effect can be achieved also through UILabel category using technique of Method Swizzling:
http://darkdust.net/writings/objective-c/method-swizzling#Step_2:_Create_the_wrapper_method

Header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UILabel (Swizzling)

- (UIFont *)swizzledFont;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "UILabel+Swizzling.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UILabel (Swizzling)

- (UIFont *)swizzledFont
{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Light" size:[[self swizzledFont] pointSize]];
}

+ (void)load
{
    Method original, swizzled;

    original = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(font));
    swizzled = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(swizzledFont));
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzled);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

in .h

> UIFont *myCustomFont;

in .m

> myCustomFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:22];
>
> [Name       setFont:myCustomFont];//Name is your UILabel//

Or right in prifix.pch file to get through out the project.

Comment: this code is the same of mine , i`ll have to set the font for each label

Answer (score 0):

Override `UIFont` as such:

Create `UIFont+SytemFontOverride.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIFont (SytemFontOverride)
@end
```

and `UIFont+SytemFontOverride.m`:

```
#import "UIFont+SytemFontOverride.h"
@implementation UIFont (SytemFontOverride)

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"

+ (UIFont *)boldSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bryant-Bold" size:fontSize];
}

+ (UIFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bryant-Regular" size:fontSize];
}

#pragma clang diagnostic pop

@end
```

Change font names accordingly.